# can not get the json variables out of json

Tags: php, json

I have this json

```
 $x = {"response":{},"status":{"detail":{"operation":"internal","errormessage":"Login session for token xxx is expired.","error":"Login session for token is expired or invalid.","errorcode":"500"},"success":false}}
```

when I try $x->success

it tells me `Trying to get property of non-object`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `json_decode` first.

Comment: It would be `$x->status->success`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First decode your json using `$data = json_decode($json_string, true);`

Then you need to access status index.

```
$data = json_decode($json_string, true);

$status = $data['status']['success'];
```

Comment: Your `$status` should be `$status = $data['status']['success'];` (missing a **`'`**

Comment: Darren Sorry for the typo, @Bora Thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [**`json_decode()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the json string to be able to access it:

```
<?php

$x = '{"response":{},"status":{"detail":{"operation":"internal","errormessage":"Login session for token xxx is expired.","error":"Login session for token is expired or invalid.","errorcode":"500"},"success":false}}';

$i = json_decode($x);

var_dump($i);

?>
```

That will allow you to test like this:

```
// checks if false
if(!$i->status->success) {....
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/168338)

Comment: $i->sucess or $i['success'] did not return anything

Comment: You should use like `$i->status->success`

Comment: @Autolycus as **Bora** stated it should be `$i->status->success`. (*stupid typos :(*)

Comment: @Autolycus did that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Let us track this code and show result at each stage for better understanding

This is your json

> $x = '{"response":{},"status":{"detail":{"operation":"internal","errormessage":"Login session for token xxx is expired.","error":"Login session for token is expired or invalid.","errorcode":"500"},"success":true}}';
>
> var_dump($x);
>
> **This will give you output as**
>
> string(207) "{"response":{},"status":{"detail":{"operation":"internal","errormessage":"Login session for token xxx is expired.","error":"Login session for token is expired or invalid.","errorcode":"500"},"success":true}}"
>
> which is a json string as you can see.

Now first json_decode() this to convert it into a json object

> $a = json_decode($x);
>
> var_dump($a);
>
> **Output of this will be**
>
> object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (0) { } ["status"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["detail"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (4) { ["operation"]=> string(8) "internal" ["errormessage"]=> string(39) "Login session for token xxx is expired." ["error"]=> string(46) "Login session for token is expired or invalid." ["errorcode"]=> string(3) "500" } ["success"]=> bool(true) } }

Which can be accessed like this

> echo $a->status->success;

Comment: Any thing new in compare of other answers ?

Comment: Sorry to be that guy but it isn't much of an explanation at all.. You could just say (*as I did*) that you need to decode it before trying to access it's properties otherwise it's just a string.